# Resetting a marker Style after another marker has been clicked

Tags: leaflet, javascript, html

Is there a way to reset a markers colour after clicking off of it.

I am trying to make the markers colour change once clicked on and then update the infobox to the name of the train station and zoom into the marker.
Upon clicking on a new marker, I would like the old markers style to be reset. I used to have this through the if statement below

```
//if clicked the circle marker changes colour and gets bigger
     function SetMarkerStyle(target) {
     if (clicked) {
     clicked.setStyle(tMarker);
     }
     target.setStyle(clickStyle);
    clicked=target;
    }
```

However, this does not work in the current situation. Is there a way to update the marker after another has been selected?

Current Code to show implementation

```
<!--MAP SCRIPT-->
<script>
<!--Instantiating the map-->
    var Leafmap = L.map('mapspce', {
    center: [51.5, -3.4],
    zoom: 9,
    scrollWheelZoon:true,
    contextmenu:true,
    locateControl:true
});



<!--Adding the tile-->
L.tileLayer('https://tile.thunderforest.com/transport/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?apikey=2392bb5236f942d8897fbe6d6c2d0c66',{
    maxZoom: 19,
    transparent: true,
    attribution: 'Tom Slater 18018815 &copy;, <a href="https://www.thunderforest.com/maps/transport/">Thunderforest</a> &copy;'
    }).addTo(Leafmap);
<!--Making a marker-->
var tMarker = {
    radius:6,
    fillColor: '#09f9df',
    color:'#ff0000',
    weight:1,
    opacity: 1,
    fillOpacity:1
};

var contentLayer =L.geoJSON(wtsGeo,{
    style: tMarker,
    onEachFeature: onEachFeature,
    pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
        return L.circleMarker(latlng, tMarker);
        }
    });
    
Leafmap.addLayer(contentLayer);

//Stores clicked marker
var clicked;

//Clicked style
var clickStyle = {
    radius:7,
    fillColor:'#ff0000',
    color:'#ff0000',
    opacity:1,
    weight:2,
    fillOpacity:1
}
//unclicked style
var unclickStyle = {
    radius:6,
    fillColor: '#09f9df',
    color:'#ff0000',
    weight:1,
    opacity: 1,
    fillOpacity:1
}

<!-- function addHandlers(feature, layer) { -->
    <!-- layer.on({ -->
        <!-- click: SetMarkerStyle -->
    <!-- }); -->
<!-- } -->

var infoWindow =L.control();

infoWindow.onAdd = function(Leafmap){
    this._div = L.DomUtil.create('div','info');
    this.update();
    return this._div;
};
    
infoWindow.update = function (statM) {
    this._div.innerHTML = '<h4>Station Name:</h4>' + (statM ? '<b>'+statM.distname:'click on marker');
};

infoWindow.addTo(Leafmap);

function SetMarkerStyle(e){
    var layer = e.target;
    layer.setStyle({
        radius:7,
        fillColor:'#ff0000',
        color:'#ff0000',
        opacity:1,
        weight:2,
        fillOpacity:1
    });
    infoWindow.update(layer.feature.properties);
    Leafmap.setView(e.latlng,13);
}

function resetClickStyle(e){
    contentLayer.resetStyle(e.target);
    infoWindow.update();
}

function zoomToFeature(e){
    Leafmap.setView(e.latlng,13);
}

function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
    layer.on({
        click:SetMarkerStyle
    });
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to call `.resetStyle()` on the GeoJSON Group. This clears the style of all markers. Or you can call `.resetStyle(layer)` then it resets only the passed layer.

1. I recommand to reset all styles when a marker is clicked and then add the new style:

```
function resetMarkerStyles(){
    contentLayer.resetStyle();
    infoWindow.update();
}

function SetMarkerStyle(e){
    resetMarkerStyles();
    var layer = e.target;
    layer.setStyle({
        radius:7,
        fillColor:'#ff0000',
        color:'#ff0000',
        opacity:1,
        weight:2,
        fillOpacity:1
    });
    infoWindow.update(layer.feature.properties);
    Leafmap.setView(e.latlng,13);
}
```

2. Add a click listener to the map, to reset the style when clicking on the map:

```
Leafmap.on('click',resetMarkerStyles);
```

But then you need to add `L.DomEvent.stopPropagation(e)` in `SetMarkerStyle` else it is called twice when clicking on the layer -> layer-click and then map-click:

```
function SetMarkerStyle(e){
    resetMarkerStyles();
    var layer = e.target;
    layer.setStyle({
        radius:7,
        fillColor:'#ff0000',
        color:'#ff0000',
        opacity:1,
        weight:2,
        fillOpacity:1
    });
    infoWindow.update(layer.feature.properties);
    Leafmap.setView(e.latlng,13);
    L.DomEvent.stopPropagation(e);
}
```